# my jquery calender is not aligning correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, clock, text-alignment

Below is the javascript for my clock on my website, it is set 2 weeks into the future however for some reason I am now getting an alert and the letterspacing (to make the calender look more square) is not working either. Can somebody please tell me why this would be? Nothing has changed and it was working perfectly grrrrrrrrrrrrr.

I repeat it worked perfectly and the letters were nicely spaced to make the whole time and date block look like a minimalist square. It is obviously something to do with this line

```
if(date > day && date > time){
```

but I do not know how to fix it.

I also have a [livelink here](http://www.cambridgedesigncompany.com/clock2.php). this will be removed for future posterity of the post.

THE JAVASCRIPT IS BELOW

```
tday = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
tmonth = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

function GetClock() {
var d = new Date(+new Date + 12096e5);
var dx = d.toGMTString();
dx = dx.substr(0, dx.length - 3);
d.setTime(Date.parse(dx))
d.setSeconds(d.getSeconds() + 0);
var nday = d.getDay(),
    nmonth = d.getMonth(),
    ndate = d.getDate(),
    nyear = d.getYear(),
    nhour = d.getHours(),
    nmin = d.getMinutes(),
    nsec = d.getSeconds(),
    ap;

if (nhour == 0) {
    ap = " AM";
    nhour = 12;
} else if (nhour < 12) {
    ap = " AM";
} else if (nhour == 12) {
    ap = " PM";
} else if (nhour > 12) {
    ap = " PM";
    nhour -= 12;
}

if (nyear < 1000) nyear += 1900;
if (nmin <= 9) nmin = "0" + nmin;
if (nsec <= 9) nsec = "0" + nsec;

document.getElementById('day').innerHTML = "" + tday[nday].toUpperCase() + "";
document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = "" + nhour + ":" + nmin + ":" + nsec + "";
document.getElementById('hour').innerHTML = "" + ap + "";
document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = "" + tmonth[nmonth].toUpperCase() + " " + ndate + ", " + nyear + "";
}

window.onload = function () {
GetClock();
setInterval(GetClock, 1000);

var day = $('#day').width();
var time = $('#time').width() + $('#hour').width() + 10;
var date = $('#date').width();

if(date > day && date > time){
 ***alert('why does this damn alert keep appearing!! Also my letter spacing isnt working anymore yet the code is untouched!');***

}else if (time > day && time > date){
    var lengthDay = $('#day').html().length-1;
    var differenceDay = time-day;
    var letterDay = differenceDay / lengthDay;

    var lengthDate = $('#date').html().length-1;
    var differenceDate = time-date;
    var letterDate = differenceDate / lengthDate;

    $('#day').css({'letter-spacing':letterDay});
    $('#date').css({'letter-spacing':letterDate});

}else{
 alert('day');
}

}
```

CSS

```
.clock {
color:#bbb;
font-size: 44px;
}
#day{
display:inline-block;
}
#time {
display:inline-block;
letter-spacing:3px;
}
#hour {
margin-left:10px;
display:inline-block;
font-size:28px;
}
#date {
font-size:30px;
display:inline-block;
} 
.text {
color:#bbb;
font-size: 24px;
}
```

Comment: Very slick looking calendar by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for sanity sake i warped the time in a span. I tried removing the if statement. So the altered onload JS now looks like this

HTML

```
<div class="text">GET YOUR CAR BY</div>
<div class="clock" id="day"></div><br>
<span id="timeHour">
  <div class="clock" id="time"></div>
  <div class="clock" id="hour"></div>
</span> <br>
<div class="clock" id="date"></div>
```

JS

```
window.onload = function () {
    GetClock();
    setInterval(GetClock, 1000);

    var day = $('#day').width();
    var time = $('#timeHour').outerWidth();
    var date = $('#date').width();


    var lengthDay = $('#day').html().length-1;
    var differenceDay = time-day;
    var letterDay = differenceDay / lengthDay;

    var lengthDate = $('#date').html().length-1;
    var differenceDate = time-date;
    var letterDate = differenceDate / lengthDate;


    $('#day').css({'letter-spacing':letterDay});
    $('#date').css({'letter-spacing':letterDate});



}
```

it seems to work for me. the day and the date now follow the size of the hour. Is that what your looking for?

Whole file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style>

  * {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.clock {
  color:#bbb;
  font-size: 44px;
}
#day{
  display:inline-block;
}
#time {
  display:inline-block;
  letter-spacing:3px;
}
#hour {
  margin-left:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:28px;
}
#date {
  font-size:30px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.text {
  display: inline-block;
  color:#bbb;
  font-size: 24px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
tday = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
tmonth = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

function GetClock() {
    var d = new Date(+new Date );
    var dx = d.toGMTString();
    dx = dx.substr(0, dx.length - 3);
    d.setTime(Date.parse(dx))
    d.setSeconds(d.getSeconds() + 0);
    var nday = d.getDay(),
        nmonth = d.getMonth(),
        ndate = d.getDate(),
        nyear = d.getYear(),
        nhour = d.getHours(),
        nmin = d.getMinutes(),
        nsec = d.getSeconds(),
        ap;

    if (nhour == 0) {
        ap = " AM";
        nhour = 12;
    } else if (nhour < 12) {
        ap = " AM";
    } else if (nhour == 12) {
        ap = " PM";
    } else if (nhour > 12) {
        ap = " PM";
        nhour -= 12;
    }

    if (nyear < 1000) nyear += 1900;
    if (nmin <= 9) nmin = "0" + nmin;
    if (nsec <= 9) nsec = "0" + nsec;

    document.getElementById('day').innerHTML = "" + tday[nday].toUpperCase() + "";
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = "" + nhour + ":" + nmin + ":" + nsec + "";
    document.getElementById('hour').innerHTML = "" + ap + "";
    document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = "" + tmonth[nmonth].toUpperCase() + " " + ndate + ", " + nyear + "";
}

window.onload = function () {
    GetClock();
    setInterval(GetClock, 1000);

    var text = $('#text').width();
    var day = $('#day').width();
    var time = $('#timeHour').width();
    var date = $('#date').width();


    var lengthDay = $('#day').html().length-1;
    var differenceDay = time-day;
    var letterDay = differenceDay / lengthDay;

    var lengthDate = $('#date').html().length-1;
    var differenceDate = time-date;
    var letterDate = differenceDate / lengthDate;

    var lengthText = $('#text').html().length-1;
    var differenceText = time-text;
    var letterText = differenceText / lengthText;


    $('#day').css({'letter-spacing':letterDay});
    $('#date').css({'letter-spacing':letterDate});
    $('#text').css({'letter-spacing':letterText});



}
</script>

<div class="text" id="text">GET YOUR CAR BY</div><br>
<div class="clock" id="day"></div><br>
<span id="timeHour">
  <div class="clock" id="time"></div>
  <div class="clock" id="hour"></div>
</span> <br>
<div class="clock" id="date"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I added letterText to the js and an id and a line break to the html and displayed .text inline-block

Comment: Hello mate, I just tried with no joy, take a look at the livelink for me and see what I havedone wrong? the actual calender can be found at www.cambridgedesigncompany.com/clock2.php

Comment: Hey you wraped the whole thing in the timeHour id i meant for you to wrap only the time and hour divs in that .

Comment: I updated my answer to add a little context to the html

Comment: thanks man your awesome! If I wanted to do the text line too the 'get your car by' how would I do that?

Comment: There you go i updated the answer to include the whole file. i just copied the date javascript and applied it to the get your car by text. just know that if that text is very long it will look bad. because the total width is based on the #timeHour div.

Comment: Don't forget to mark my answer as correct if it is :-)